# conditional knockout with ajax response

Tags: ajax, knockoutjs, mini-cart, condition

I created an default template for items in the minicart. The difference to the default template should be shown only under a specific condition.

```
<!-- ko if: $parent.myvalueactive(product_sku)==true -->
   some stuff
<!-- /ko -->
```

I added a function in my javascript file, that gets loaded with the minicart:

```
myvalueactive: function (target) {
              console.log(target);                  
              var aktiviert;


              $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "mymodule/index/active",
                data: { q: target},
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success : function(response){
                  if (response.aktiv=='true') {
                      aktiviert='true';
                  };                  
                }
              });

              if (aktiviert=="true") {
                return true;
              }
              else {
                return false;
              }
            }
```

This works so far on the product pages and CMS-pages. However, it doesnt work in the checkout process - The content isnt loaded in the minicart on the cart-page nor on the checkout page. 
Did I mess up ajax or something. Im not even sure, what to search for, for debugging....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. My mistake was the url in the ajax request. I needed to add a slash in front of the url, to make it work on other pages:

```
              $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/mymodule/index/active",   //added a slash in front of the url
                data: { q: target},
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success : function(response){
                  if (response.aktiv=='true') {
                      aktiviert='true';
                  };                  
                }
              });
```